# Android Unexpected Shutdown

Tags: android

I've tried to get some data from the nasa rss ( I'm following Android HeadFirst book ) using the Simple Framework.
The problem that I face is that the application closes down automatically when the main activity is loaded.

Here is the code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
        print();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and here is the print method:

```
public void print() throws Exception
{
    Rss rss = new Rss();
    Serializer serializer = new Persister();
    File source = new File("http://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/image_of_the_day.rss");
    serializer.read(rss, source);
     TextView text = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageTitle);
     text.setText(rss.channel.title);
}
```

logcat:

```
> 12-11 18:27:03.459: D/AndroidRuntime(20621): Shutting down VM
12-11 18:27:03.459: W/dalvikvm(20621): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400205a0)
12-11 18:27:03.469: E/AndroidRuntime(20621): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-11 18:27:03.469: E/AndroidRuntime(20621): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nasadailyimage/com.example.nasadailyimage.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.nasadailyimage.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.nasadailyimage-1.apk]
12-11 18:27:03.469: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1743)
12-11 18:27:03.469: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1851)
12-11 18:27:03.469: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
12-11 18:27:03.469: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
12-11 18:27:03.469: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-11 18:27:03.469: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
12-11 18:27:03.469: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
12-11 18:27:03.469: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 18:27:03.469: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-11 18:27:03.469: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-11 18:27:03.469: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-11 18:27:03.469: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-11 18:27:03.469: E/AndroidRuntime(20621): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.nasadailyimage.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.nasadailyimage-1.apk]
12-11 18:27:03.469: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
12-11 18:27:03.469: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
12-11 18:27:03.469: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
12-11 18:27:03.469: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1040)
12-11 18:27:03.469: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1735)
12-11 18:27:03.469: E/AndroidRuntime(20621):    ... 11 more
```

Here is the manifest file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.nasadailyimage"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.nasadailyimage.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I've create a brand new android project. And it works

However even if I remove all the libraries I added ( simple.org) and if I comment out everything that I've added in MainActivity.java is **still** makes the application close down

I have been able to observe that the line:

```
Serializer serialezer = new Persister();
```

causes the error. Is the framework simple used for android applications? Does it usually cause these kind of errors?

**Update**

I have also tried different versions of the jar.
None seem to work

Closing Eclipse does not help whatsoever

The program only runs when the Serializer line is *commented* out

Comment: how about a logcat stacktrace?

Comment: Can you please post the full stack trace?

Comment: @vandus . Collin Flynn sorry for late response. I had to update my plugins in order to get the logcat. It is here now

Comment: Maybe the package name does not match the name in your manifest. Does it run when you don't call print()? Please post the manifest file

Comment: And is MainActivity located in the package com.example.nasadailyimage?

Comment: @FlatEric I have added the AndroidManifest.xml file. It does not run when I comment the print method out. I'm 100% it is in the right package http://i.imgur.com/InCDifo.png

Comment: Is this built in Android Studio or Eclipse?

Comment: @ScottBarta  This is built in ADT ( Eclipse )

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
Serializer ser = new Persister();
```

is what causes the error. I don't have the smallest idea weather the simple Framework is causing this somehow.

Comment: how about you change the absolute path to MainActivity to a relative one? meaning ".MainActivity" instead of "com.example.nasadailyimage.MainActivity"